# Get a value from user-secrets for use in the dotnet CLI

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, command-line-interface

How do I pull a value from user-secrets for use in a dotnet command?

The best I can do at the moment is:

```
$c = dotnet user-secrets list
```

Shows me: AppSettings:MyConnectionString = "Value of the connection string"

```
$c.GetType() //tells me BaseType = System.Object, Name = String, etc.
```

Now I can potentially try to extract the value of the connection string but that doesn't seem like a good way to do it.

I want to use the user-secret in the command:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold <MyConnectionString> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models
```

If I enter it in manually, then the database credentials will be stored in the command line history and I will get a warning in Visual Studio about how to protect potentially sensitive information by including it in my configuration file. However, I want to use user-secrets for development rather than adding the connection string to my configuration file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `dotnet user-secrets list --json` to get the values in machine-readable format. Then you can use PowerShell's `ConvertFrom-Json` to turn the output into a `PSCustomObject` where each secret key is available as a `NoteProperty`.

```
$secrets = dotnet user-secrets list --json | ConvertFrom-Json
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold $secrets.'AppSettings:MyConnectionString' ...
```

(The quotes around the secret name are only necessary when you have a non-alphanumeric character in the name.)

**NB**

For some unfathomable reason, the JSON is wrapped by `//BEGIN` and `//END`.

```json
//BEGIN
{
  "AppSettings:MyConnectionString": "Data Source=..."
}
//END
```

PowerShell 7 ignores the comments, but if you are using Windows PowerShell then you get an error.

> ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: .

A possible workaround for this error is to remove `//BEGIN` and `//END` using the `-replace` operator. Another workaround is to skip the first and the last lines.

```
# Using Windows PowerShell
$json = dotnet user-secrets list --json
$secrets = $json | % { $_ -replace '//(BEGIN|END)' } | ConvertFrom-Json
# or
$secrets = $json | select -Skip 1 | select -SkipLast 1 | ConvertFrom-Json
```